# Doing effective null check in MVEL expression for a non existent field

Tags: expression, mvel

I have the below json input

```
{
"fieldA": "fieldNameABC",
"fieldB": "REVERSE"}
```

I am trying to do a null check on a non-existent field `fieldC` and if it's present, will map the value as below -

```
if(input.fieldC!=null) {
  output = input.fieldC; }
```

Its throwing `[Error: could not access: fieldC`. Is it possible to check for a field existence in MVEL. If yes, how can this statement be corrected. Have tried `empty` syntax but same issue.